# How to find the frequency of list of words in a DataFrame using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

my `df` looks like this:

```
category       text_list
--------       ---------
soccer         [soccer, game, is, good, soccer, game]
basketball     [game, basketball, game]
volleyball     [sport ,volleyball, sport]
```

What I want to do is `groupby` `category` and then list the `words` by its `frequency`

```
category       text_list          frequency
--------       ---------          ---------
soccer         soccer             2
               game               2 
               is                 1
               good               1
basketball     game               2
               basketball         1  
volleyball     sport              2
               volleyball         1
```

what did I do?

- I am able to find the `frequency` per row but I am not able to label the way I wanted in a `DataFrame`

Could someone please help me? If possible using `NLTK`

Answer (score 2):

Try `explode` then `groupby`:

```
(df.explode('text_list')
   .groupby(['category','text_list']).size()
   .to_frame(name='frequency')
)
```

Output:

```
                       frequency
category   text_list            
basketball basketball          1
           game                2
soccer     game                2
           good                1
           is                  1
           soccer              2
volleyball sport               2
           volleyball          1
```

Comment: thank you for composing the answer. however my `Pandas` installation is limited to `0.22.0` and `explode` is not supported

Comment: @floss have a look at [this `unnest` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/4238408) as a substitution.